# Is there a way to find if there exists a solution such that all the variables in a system of linear equations are either 0 or 1 in P time?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Note this is different from Binary Integer Programming as it does not involve inequalities.

An example would be a+b = 1. A solution would be a = 0, b = 1. I just want 1 solution, or even if there exists a solution. I think this should be possible but have no idea how to proceed about it. I was reading this http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~sk1233/courses/ANT-F14/lec3.pdf where they can find integer solutions in P time, I was not sure how this can be switched to find solutions which are only 0 or 1.

It would be great if it could be explained in easy terms so a 2nd-3rd year math/cs student in college could understand. And if anyone can provide a solver or a library or code which can solve it would be of great great help.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd be surprised, given that SAT is NP-complete.

Comment: However thiis does not solve SAT. This is not even integer linear programming. So how does this being in P interfere with SAT being NP-complete?

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand your remarks, but if you can find integer solutions efficiently, you can use that exact procedure to find 0-1 solutions efficiently.

Comment: Thats what I am thinking too, though I personally don't quite comprehend the algo presented in the paper to find integer solutions. Even still I cannot see a direct reduction see a+b = 1, what if I get a = 2, and b = -1?